# Android add Language XML (strings.xml) in res folder at runtime

Tags: android, android-resources

I have an android app which has 3 languages in `res` folder.

- English
- French
- Chinese

I want my app to add another language at runtime  in `res` folder and not by adding string xml files and recompile them.

How can i achieve this? I've search alot in google and no luck.

Thanks alot!!

Comment: You can't add something to the `res` folder at runtime.

Comment: So, is it possible to load string.xml in external location?

Comment: You can load all the strings from `strings.xml` but I don't see how would this benefit you as you still can't modify and write back the strings for the new language, so you would need to modify the text for each of the strings manually. Why(or for what) do you need to add the new language at runtime? And from where would the new `strings.xml` come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirmed that this is not possible because all files in res folder are **read-only**

Comment: You could have a second source for strings and check programatically whether a string resource exists in resources before using this second source. The second source could be a map held in memory and loaded in at runtime.

Comment: @DavidCaunt can you please tell more about how to add 'second source'?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem and I will just get all strings from a (cached) remote file.
The TextView text property will store an id and in the Activity.onCreate() method I'll programatically replace all TextViews.text strings with it's matched value from the current language file.